# SP2010 Designer Workflow: Wait Until ([Date&Time Field] - 1 Hour)

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, date-time

I have a "DoneBy" Date & Time field on my custom "Tasks" List.

The requirement is to send an email reminder when there's 1 hour left until "DoneBy".

Is it possible to achieve this using "Wait" in the workflow?

If not, should I use another calculated field ("DoneBy" - one hour) and use it in the workflow instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Wait" won't allow you to do the subtraction within that statement.  You could set up a workflow variable that equals DoneBy - 1 hour, then set the Wait.

Example:

```
 1. Set <workflow variable> to DoneBy 
 2. Add -1 hours to <workflow variable> (Output to <output workflow variable>)
 3. Wait for DoneBy to equal <output workflow variable>
```

Comment: Thanks! I am not so familiar with workflows, didn't even know that you can have custom variables... :) Your solution makes sense, I will try it first thing tomorrow and accept the answer if it works, +1 for now :)

Comment: I'm happy to help! Let me know if you have any further questions about the specifics of writing it all out.

Comment: Well, that's what this community is all about :) On a 3rd step I had to compare my variable with current time, not a `DoneBy` field with my variable. With `Wait` condition you can only compare an item field with a function, so in my case I ended up using `Pause` instead. So my first 2 steps were like you suggested, but the third statement was `Pause until <output workflow variable>` :) Thanks once again!